# Notification bar on website - how to avoid multiple notifications for same user

Tags: caching, asp.net-mvc-2

I am building a website that will notify users of certain changes to their account via a notification bar at the top of the screen (similar to the way SO notifies of new badges).

In my DB I have a table that list the events and also a flag to denote whether they have been notified of the change yet or not. The table is of the form :

```
UserID     AccountEvent      EventDescription                  HasBeenNotified
ABC123     1                 Your price deal ends in 2 weeks   FALSE
```

What I would like to achieve is:

1. Customer logs in and is shown notification (assuming one needs to
   happen)
2. Customer clicks to acknowledge message
3. DB `HasBeenNotified` field set to `TRUE` (to acknowledge notification has occurred)

I have been able to achieve all this but there is a snag!

I am putting the events that need to be notified into the `HttpRuntime.Cache` with a 10 min expiry so I don't need to keep polling the DB.

The issue this creates for me is that a customer could potentially see multiple notifications of the same message until the cache expires, for example:

1. Customer logs in and app logic looks in cache and says customer `ABC123` needs to be
   notified of X
2. Customer then acknowledges message (which updates DB to set notification flag to TRUE)
3. Cache does not yet reflect updated DB so if customer navigates to new page the same notification message is fired (until cache expires)

As far as I know I cannot update the actual data within the Cache (can only `Remove` data from cache based on cache key).

Can anybody provide hints and tips of how to get around the issue of multiple notifications?

Answer (score 0):

Why not burst the cache?  Remove that key from the cache?

Or you **can update** the cache by setting it again to new HasBeenNotified value or even set it to null which you should deal with and accept as empty.

```
HttpRuntime.Cache["YourKey"] = "";//new object/value;
```

Comment: the data in the cache is for *all* customers, so removing the key from the cache means I will have to keep going to the DB to refresh it i.e. the reason I want it in the cache is so that I don't need to go to the DB for each user login to check if they need to get a message or not. Does that make sense?

Comment: makes sense to cache this but why not make a key for each user, using their Id as part of the key.  How many users have you got?

Comment: I did think about that as it solves the issue. I am *naive* when it come to caching but I may have up to 50k+ customers and I wondered if having 50K+ keys would hamper performance (isn't a cache just a dictionary with key value pairs???)

Comment: they are key value.  50k is a lot but if they are short lived and tiny it's not too scary.  Another way to think of it is this.  Store one global notification, then only add a per user item into the cache if they have seen it and only display if they haven't got this cache value.  That way you're only putting the number of active users into the cache.